# How to write unit test in java for loading file

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mockito

I want to perform unit test to check file loading in java. I saw some posts on *Mockitos doThrow* but don't get the implementation of it exactly.

My method looks something like this.

```
    public void loadPropertiesFile(String filepath){
    logger.info("Loading properties file");
    try{
        prop.load(new FileInputStream(filepath));
        logger.info("Properties file read");
    }catch(IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        logger.info("Properties file read error");
    }
}
```

I was trying to test it like this but getting error on improper usage of doThrow:

```
@Test
    public void loadPropertiesFileTestTrue(){
        Utility util=new Utility();

        doThrow(FileNotFoundException.class)
            .when(util)
            .loadPropertiesFile(null);

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `doThrow()` method on mocked objects only.

You should change your code like this:

```
@Test
public void loadPropertiesFileTestTrue(){
     Utility util=Mockito.mock(Utility.class);

     doThrow(FileNotFoundException.class)
            .when(util)
            .loadPropertiesFile(null);

}
```